# How to validate a file name which has a date in it using a C# regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I want to verify the file name with the specified format(YYYYMMDDHHmmRate).for eg , if my file name is 201109301030Rate.XML i have to verify it with specified format.can anybody help me how to do it in C#

Comment: Depending on how strict you want to be with the validation, this might not be a good fit for regex. Do you need to make sure that it's a valid date, or just that it just possibly be a date?

Comment: I just want to check that it follows the date and time format for eg,month should not be greater then 12 etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a regex to check the formatting is close and then try to parse to date to check it's valid.

```
var fileRegex = new Regex(@"^(?<Date>\d{12})Rate$");
var match = fileRegex.Match(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName));

DateTime fileNameDate;
bool success = match.Success && 
                   DateTime.TryParseExact(
                      match.Groups["Date"].Value,
                      "yyyyMMddHHmm",
                      CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
                      DateTimeStyles.None, 
                      out fileNameDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to accept some invalid dates, here's a suggestion:

```
foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, 
    @"^                           # Start of string
    (?:19|20)[0-9]{2}             # Year
    (?:0[1-9]|1[012])             # Month
    (?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])    # Day
    (?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3])          # Hour
    [0-5][0-9]                    # Minute
    \.xml                         # .XML
    $                             # End of string", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

This will accept February 31st and other nonlegal dates, but parsing dates is generally better done with other means than regex anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression that confirms that variable portion of the name is all digits is easy enough:

```
^\d{12}Rate\.XML$
```

However creating a regular expression that checks the date is valid would be rather hard (because the fields interact: eg. the year affects month lengths). So easier to parse the date/time and use that to perform the detailed check:

```
DateTime dummy;
if (Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\d{12}Rate\.XML$") 
   && DateTime.TryParseExact(input.SubString(0, 12),
                             "yyyyMMddHHmm", appropriateCultureInfo,
                             DateTimeStyles.None,
                             out dummy)) {
  // It is OK.
}
```

Comment: Just to be picky, the Ys and Ds need to be lowercase.